# Use app made by me in iOS without distributing it in appstore

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Is it possible to use app made by me in my iphone without distributing it in appstore?

If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It's a little convoluted process but it's not difficult and it can be done without a *Apple Developer* account.

There are quite a few steps but it simply involves creating your app in Xcode, connecting your iPhone to the Mac, and deploying your app to your iPhone.  The complete info on how to do this are on [this Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html).

Comment: This does not answer the specific question, which relates only to using an app that has not been approved in the app store. Any developer account within Apple can do this, paid or unpaid.

Comment: @drew.. The answer exactly addresses the specific question and it was accepted by the OP almost a year ago.  Your comment doesn't really make sense.  If you'd like to improve the answer, please feel free to suggest an edit and it will be evaluated by the mods.